# Errors but compiling xetex

Tags: xetex, errors, compiling

I use xelatex for my thesis. This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

and later in my document i use the align to render an equation

```
\begin{align*}
    \forall s \in Q, \forall w \in \Sigma^\ast, \forall \alpha \in \Sigma, & ~ \delta (s, \epsilon) = s, \delta (s, w\alpha )=\delta (\delta (s, w), \alpha  ); \\
    & ~ \sigma (s, \epsilon )= \epsilon, \sigma (s, w\spaha)= \sigma (s,   w)\sgima (\delta (s,w), \alpha ).
\end{align*}
```

But when i compile it with TexMaker it says finished with errors. The pdf output though is ok. The errors i get from log file have to do with the \end{align} that is undefined

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on )= \epsilon , \sigma (s, w\spaha 
                                              )= \sigma (s, w)\sgima (\d...

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... (s, w\spaha )= \sigma (s, w)\sgima 
                                              (\delta (s,w), \alpha ). 
l.71 \end{align*}
```

Is there a problem with my equation? It renders normally and correctly on my pdf document

If i uncomment amssymb i get different errors like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Finv' already defined.

! LaTeX Error: Command `\Game' already defined.

! LaTeX Error: Command `\beth' already defined.

! LaTeX Error: Command `\daleth' already defined.
```

I used amssymb before but with latex and didn't have issues. Any help?

Texlive 2009 i think (Ubuntu 12.04) and Texmaker 3.2 my env

Comment: Never heard about a `\spaha` command; also `\sgima` is a misprint for `\sigma`.

Comment: lol...damn..second time my eyes play tricks on me....!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\spaha` is an external command and must be defined elsewhere. However, you should load *all* font specific stuff *before* `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\let\spaha\relax%% because I do not know the meaning

\begin{document}

and later in my document i use the align to render an equation

\begin{align*}
    \forall s \in Q, \forall w \in \Sigma^\ast, \forall \alpha \in \Sigma, & ~ \delta (s, \epsilon) = s, \delta (s, w\alpha )=\delta (\delta (s, w), \alpha  ); \\
    & ~ \sigma (s, \epsilon )= \epsilon, \sigma (s, w\spaha)= \sigma (s,   w)\sigma (\delta (s,w), \alpha ).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And TeXLive 2009 is a really old version. Current is 2013

Comment: Thank you..it works fine now...I thought it was backwards meaning that xltxtra was loading fontspec...its the opposite i think :)